# How to populate Flutter DataTable with JSON API?

Tags: flutter

I've successfully displayed a hardcoded JSON with a DataTable, like this:
[image]

```
  final List<Map<String, String>> listOfPetrol = [
    {"logo": "assets/images/shell.jpg", "location": "Johnson Road 1235", "distance": "0.2 KM", "price":"\$12.45", "facilities":"ATM, Restaurant"},
    {"logo": "assets/images/sinopec.jpg", "location": "Hennessy Road", "distance": "0.5 KM", "price":"\$10.00", "facilities":"Toilet"},
    {"logo": "assets/images/shell.jpg", "location": "Lockhart Rd", "distance": "0.9 KM", "price":"\$11.20", "facilities":"ATM"}
  ];


 DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Logo')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Location')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Distance')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
                      DataColumn(label: Text('Facilities')),
                    ],
                    rows:
                    listOfPetrol
                        .map(
                      ((element) => DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(Image.asset(element["logo"])),
                          DataCell(Text(element["location"])),
                          DataCell(Text(element["distance"])),
                          DataCell(Text(element["price"])),
                          DataCell(Text(element["facilities"])),
                        ],
                      )),
                    )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
```

Now, I want fetch the JSON from HTTP API, instead. I already figured out this part. Well... kinda:

```
FetchPetrolList() async {
    var data = await http.get("http://157.230.131.4/gda-api-dev/petrol.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<PetrolItem> petrolList = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      PetrolItem petrol = PetrolItem(u["logo"], u["location"], u["distance"], u["price"], u["facilities"]);
      petrolList.add(petrol);
      print(petrol.logo+" "+petrol.location+" "+petrol.distance+" "+petrol.price+" "+petrol.facilities);
    }
  }
```

Then how I pass the JSON to the DataTable?
Full code: https://gist.github.com/anta40/5b172d885795c71417f2ed2dccffe50c

Answer (score 1):

You can parse JSON data into a model. There are two ways I use to parse JSON data automatically.

1. [On-line Generation](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

[image]

2. Install Flutter JsonBeanFactory plug-in generation

Android studio installs the Flutter JsonBeanFactory plug-in in a simple way, which I won't say here.

Right-click the package directory after installation, and select new

[image]

Then select dart bean class File from JSON

[image]

Then paste the JSON data into the input box, enter the class name, and click make.

[image]

So the entity class is generated.

Comment: OK I think I got it. Here's my solution: https://gist.github.com/anta40/0fca94cb8488cdc031c4536bc552cd8f. Basically it calls FetchPetrolList() on setState(). Then some tiny adjustments related to DataRow.  I wonder if there's a better approach, though.